# R merging two tables by one column

Tags: r, merge, datatable

I have the following two tables:

```
dt.testNr <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,20,6,7,8,9,100))
dt.test <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), l=c(100,12920,2129,12929,12,19292,192291,14,14,2))
```

Now I want to merge them, but don't get the result I wanted:

```
merge(dt.testNr, dt.test)
```

I have already tried some `all.x` and `all.y`, `by.x` and `by.y` commands.
I need in the end a table, which has exactly the column `a` of `dt.testNr` and column  `b` of `dt.test`, but for `a=20` an `NA`-value and for `a=100` also an `NA`-value, because these numbers where not find in `dt.test`.

Comment: Why doesn't `all.x=TRUE` work? I get exactly what you described with that.

Comment: I need exacly the right order of column a. Here 20 and 100 where placed in the bottom. 20 should stay at row 5 and 100 at row 10.

Comment: In reality my two data tables are about 300.000 entries, and the order of the first column of table 1 should stay the same.

Comment: Gotcha; see my answer below.

Comment: I wasn't describing it clear enough, sorry for that. Thank you so much for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

To merge the two data sets while maintaining the original rows of the first, you can use `all.x = TRUE`. To also maintain the original order, you can use the `sort = FALSE` option of the **data.table** `merge()` function.

```r
dt.testNr <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,20,6,7,8,9,100))
dt.test <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), l=c(100,12920,2129,12929,12,19292,192291,14,14,2))
merge(dt.testNr, dt.test, all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

This produces:

```
      a      l
 1:   1    100
 2:   2  12920
 3:   3   2129
 4:   4  12929
 5:  20     NA
 6:   6  19292
 7:   7 192291
 8:   8     14
 9:   9     14
10: 100     NA
```